# Linker can't find overloaded operator<< while compiling. C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, std, display, heap

I am working on implementing a templated heap class. It has been really rough so far.
I am trying to display my heap but I am getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Heap<int> const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I used template in my class so the implementation of my functions in inside the header file as well, here is the hpp file:
(!): No need to read the whole file, just the ostream& operator<<().

```
/*
 Header file for Heap implemenetation
 */

#ifndef Heap_hpp
#define Heap_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>



template<typename elementType>
class Heap{
private:
    std::vector<elementType> myVecrtor;
    int mySize = 1; //The minimum size is 1 since the first element is a dummy.
    void perculateDown(int root);
    void perculateUp();
    
public:
    Heap();
    bool checkEmpty();
    void insert(elementType iteam);
    int getSize();
    std::vector<elementType> getHeap();
    elementType getMax();
    int getMaxIndex();
    void removeMax();
    void removeAtIndex(int index);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, Heap const &h);
    
};

template<typename elementType>
Heap<elementType>::Heap(){
}

template <typename elementType>
bool Heap<elementType>::checkEmpty(){
    if(mySize > 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

template <typename elementType>
void Heap<elementType>::insert(elementType iteam){
    auto it = mySize;//iterator
    //myVecrtor.insert(it, iteam);//insert after first element(dummy)
    mySize++;
    perculateUp();
}

template <typename elementType>
std::vector<elementType> Heap<elementType>::getHeap(){
    return  myVecrtor;
}

template <typename elementType>
elementType Heap<elementType>::getMax(){
    return myVecrtor[getMaxIndex()];
}

template <typename elementType>
int Heap<elementType>::getMaxIndex(){
    int maxIndex = 1;
    elementType max = myVecrtor[maxIndex];
    for(int i = 0; i < myVecrtor.size(); i++){
        if(max < myVecrtor[i])
            maxIndex = i;
    }
    return maxIndex;
}

template <typename elementType>
void Heap<elementType>::removeMax(){
    int maxIndex = getMaxIndex();
    myVecrtor[maxIndex] = myVecrtor[mySize];
    mySize--;
    perculateDown(maxIndex);
}

template <typename elementType>
void Heap<elementType>::removeAtIndex(int index){
    myVecrtor[index] = myVecrtor[mySize];
    mySize--;
    perculateDown(index);
}

template <typename elementType>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Heap<elementType> &h){//it is giving me the error here
    out<<"\t\tHeap:";
    for(int i = 0; i < h.mySize; i++){
        out<<h.myVecrtor.at(i);
    }
    return out;
}

template <typename elementType>
void Heap<elementType>::perculateUp(){
    int loc = mySize - 1;
    int parent = loc /2;
   // while(parent >= 1 && myVecrtor[loc] > myVecrtor[parent]){
        elementType temp = myVecrtor[parent];
        myVecrtor[parent] = myVecrtor[loc];
        myVecrtor[loc] = temp;
        loc = parent;
        parent = loc / 2;
   // }
}

template <typename elementType>
void Heap<elementType>::perculateDown(int root){
    int r = root, c = r*2;
    while (r < mySize - 1) {
        if(c < mySize && myVecrtor[c] < myVecrtor[c+1])
            c++;
        if(myVecrtor[r] < myVecrtor[c]){
            elementType temp = myVecrtor[r];
            myVecrtor[r] = myVecrtor[c];
            myVecrtor[c] = temp;
            r = c;
            c *= 2;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
}


#endif /* Heap_hpp */
```

I tried all my other functions to see if I had a silly mistake or something but all worked except this one:
(!): ik the use of namespace std is a bad habbit but i am using just for testing

```
#include <vector>
#include "Heap.hpp"
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Heap<int> h;
    h.insert(5);
    h.getHeap();
    h.getMaxIndex();
    h.getMax();
    h.removeMax();
    h.removeAtIndex(1);
    h.getHeap();
    cout<<h;
    
}
```

I have no idea what's the problem, tho one thing I found very close to my problem is related to the namespace std, but didn't get anything out of it.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you aware that C++ already has [heap functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The friend declaration for `operator<<` that you currently have is for a non-template `operator<<`.

There are 2 ways to solve this:

##### Method 1

To **solve** this replace that friend declaration with a declaration that has its own **parameter clause** so that you've a **friend template declaration**, inside the class with:

```
template<typename elementType>
class Heap{
    //other code as before
    public:
        template<typename U>
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, Heap<U> const &h);
    
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/VBDIZAls1)

##### Method 2

Here we can forward declare both the class template `Heap` and `operator<<`.

```
//forward declaration for Heap<> 
template<typename T> class Heap;

//forward declaration for operator<<
template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Heap<T> const &h);

template<typename elementType>
class Heap{
  //other members as before
    
public:

    friend std::ostream& operator<<<elementType>(std::ostream &out, Heap<elementType> const &h);
    
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/n7mA7BvDG)

Comment: *The friend declaration for operator<< that you currently have is for a non-template operator<<* - provided `Heap` is a class with template, when will such operator work?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind See [this live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/MxxNRPWL4) for working of such non-template `operator<<`.

Comment: I tried but then it wouldn;t let me use the private members of the class "h.mySize" and "h.myVector" nor see my public functions like h.removeAtIndex().

Comment: Note: Now it was able to locate it and call except I can't use the members as mentioned.

Comment: @Youssof.K. I've provided 2 live demos in my answer. Did you click on them and tried them? They work so you can't say that it doesn't work. You can match you code with those live demos and find out where the problem is. They are the exact copy of you code except that i have applied the solutions mentioned in my answer to them so that you can go line by line and match with your code and find the problem. Again, make sure that you're using `std::ostream` instead of `ostream` inside all header and source files. [Demo1](https://onlinegdb.com/VBDIZAls1) and [Demo2](https://onlinegdb.com/n7mA7BvDG).

Comment: Yes my debugger seems to take a while to realize new code written, i just waited a while and when got back it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @AnoopRana Can we enter a chat room I am facing multiple problems in my C++ code and I am still a beginner. So many little details to deal with it's so frustrating

Comment: @Youssof.K. I recommend using some [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You can send me the link for the chat room but i can't promise that i can reply instantly as i am quite busy. But i will come there in the chat room once in a while to see if there are any messages.